# Changing div class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I try to develop some charts which should have online values. I have found this nice and free dashboard : 
[http://jiji262.github.io/Bootstrap_Metro_Dashboard/][1]
I use Web sockets to change values of charts and it works very nice. I use justgage([http://justgage.com/][2]) plug-in. As you can see there are some square shapes with different colors(Disk Space Usage,Bandwidth,memory,CPU etc.) and i want to change color of these squares according to values.

Here is div construction :

```
<div class="span2" onTablet="span4" onDesktop="span2"> 
            <div ID="ID1" class="circleStatsItemBox green"> 
            <div class="header">Machine 1</div> 
              <span class="percent"></span> 
            <div class="circleStat">    
               <div id="g1"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="f1" class="footer">
                <span class="number">cards/hour</span>
            </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

g1 is justgage gauge and i use this code to change div class : (to change of square)

> $('#ID1').addClass('circleStatsItemBox green').removeClass('circleStatsItemBox orange');

But this code changes title and footer color as same with body color. I want that footer and header color should be arranged according to new div class (for example according to circleStatsItemBox orange at my sample)

Thanks

Comment: use jquery toggleClass or addClass/removeClass methods. reference here http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to remove before adding:

```
$('#ID1').removeClass('circleStatsItemBox orange').addClass('circleStatsItemBox green');
```

Comment: Note that you're first removing cirleStatsItemBox and then adding it again. Should be `$('#ID1').removeClass('orange').addClass('green');`

Answer (score 1):

try with `toggleClass` in jquery.

**ToggleClass**: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.

```
$('#ID1.circleStatsItemBox').toggleClass('orange green');
```

Comment: I have learnt toggle function with your post. In fact that it will work to flash squares to warn my users. Thanks for your effort.